# grammarly alternative - NLP

Tags: python, nlp

I'm trying to learn NLP with python. Although I work with a variety of programming languages I'm looking for some kind of from the ground up solution that I can put together to come up with a product that has a high standard of spelling and grammer like grammerly?

I've tried some approaches with python. https://pypi.org/project/inflect/ 
Spacy for parts of speech.

Could someone point me in the direction of some kind of fully fledged API, that I can pull apart and try and work out how to get to a decent standard of english, like grammerly.

Many thanks,
Vince.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to checkout Stanford core nlp, nltk as a start. but if you want to train your own ner and symantic modeling gensim.